# I'm gettin error about something call "Lambda"

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.ozellikler)
    {
        if (item.ozellikAtama != null && item.ozellikAtama == 0)
        {
            \<h3\>@item.ozellikAdi\</h3\>
            var filteredOzellikler = Model.ozellikler.Where(m =\> m.ozellikAtama == item.id).ToList();
            foreach (var ozellik in filteredOzellikler)
            {
                \<p\>@ozellik.ozellikAdi\</p\>
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message => CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type about =>var filteredOzellikler = Model.ozellikler.Where(m => m.ozellikAtama == item.id).ToList();

I tried everything, but still not working.

Comment: C# is a language of types, what is the type of `Model.ozellikler`? Why does your posted code have so many backslashes?

Comment: I solved, in the viewpage (cshtml) i forgot add at the top @model MyContextModel